# Is there a "fake" mobile app with bugs that can be used for practise?

Tags: mobile, learning

I'm aware of some web applications that offer "fake" sites (usually with bugs inserted on purpose) so testers can learn and practise, like http://automationpractice.com or https://www.demoblaze.com.

However, I'm not sure if there's something like that when it comes to mobile applications (I'm talking about applications that run natively, not simply websites that are optimized to run in mobile versions). I only found one: https://github.com/saucelabs/sample-app-mobile but I don't think it has bugs inserted for learning/practising purposes.

Are there any more?

Comment: For black box tests I would pick up any low rated app, eg. with one star, from Google Play.

Answer (score -1):

I guess this may help with what you are looking for:

http://mrbuggy.pl/mrbuggy8/

https://www.eviltester.com/page/tools/buggyapps/

https://github.com/eviltester/TestingApp/tree/master/java/testingapps/compendiumdevapps/src/main/resources/web/apps

A list of open source applications:

https://github.com/pcqpcq/open-source-android-apps